# How to prevent Setup Project in Visual Studio to prompt for .Net Core runtime installation

Tags: .net-core, windows-installer, setup-project

How can I build my .msi and this one is not going to prompt the user for .net core runtime installation? As I have included this file embedded and will install manually later on. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2019

Comment: Thanks Leszek P, I did. I used publish items and on the setup project I unchecked the prerequisites box. But I get prompted to install .net core anyways directly from the .msi I'm sure there has to be an xml tag for this on the .vdproj or similar. As a work around I am adding the published output as a zip file to my forms app resource directory together with the .netcore runtime installer, which is the goal to make it easier for the user,  unzipping the site on first run. But this means I have to pack it manually everytime there's a change.